# Select rows between two dates where dates are variables

Tags: php, sql, date, select, rows

I have an SELECT statement in php and I need to select all rows of the table where the "date" column is in between a start date and end date that will be defined by variables.

I have this working perfectly fine when I define the dates directly in the SELECT statement as shown below:

```
date BETWEEN "2015-02-03" AND "2015-02-05"
```

However, when I try to do the same thing but with variables, it doesn't seem to work:

```
date BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate"
```

Where

```
$startdate = "2015-02-03";
$enddate = "2015-02-05";
```

Hope all this makes sense, Cheers in advance.

Full code snippet is here as requested:

```
$startdate = "2015-02-03";
$enddate = "2015-02-05";

$sql = 'SELECT record_number, date, manmod, description, cal, serial, datein, dateout, retdate, refex, refexdate, sellersname, sellersaddress, buyersname, buyersaddress, rfddealer, del, warranty, months FROM record WHERE del="Live" AND date BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate" ORDER BY record_number DESC';
```

Comment: Since the first query (without variable dates) works fine, the problem probably lies in PHP building the query. Can you verify that the query that is being executed, is OK?

Comment: Can you show your full snippet please?

Comment: just added full code snippet, thanks

Comment: Does using curly braces work? `date BETWEEN "{$startdate}" AND "{$enddate}"`

Comment: Curly brackets doesn't seem to have an effect im afraid

Comment: Try: `$sql = "SELECT record_number, date, manmod, description, cal, serial, datein, dateout, retdate, refex, refexdate, sellersname, sellersaddress, buyersname, buyersaddress, rfddealer, del, warranty, months FROM record WHERE del='Live' AND date BETWEEN '{$startdate}' AND '{$enddate}' ORDER BY record_number DESC";` What's the output to `echo $sql;` in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP website](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Note: Unlike the [double-quoted](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and [heredoc](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntaxes, [variables](https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted [string](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)s.

In other words, since your query is in single quotes, the `$startdate` and `$enddate` variables are not interpreted as variables. The SQL query that is send to the database will literally contain `$startdate` and `$enddate`, and will therefore look something like this:

```
'SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate" ORDER BY record_number DESC';
```

(I've simplified the query a bit for readability purposes)

Obviously, the database does not know how to interpret PHP variables, it will look for records with a date between those two strings, finds nothing and therefore returns 0 records.

In order to paste the contents of the variables in your SQL query, you will have to do one of two things:

## Option 1: replace the single quotes with double quotes

If you choose this option, make sure that you either escape the existing double quotes, or change them into single quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' ORDER BY record_number DESC";
```

## Option 2: concatenate the strings manually

You can also build op the query manually from multiple parts, and glue them together using PHP's concatenation operator, the dot (`.`).

```
$sql = 'SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate;
```

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen we have a winner, take a bow sir.

Comment: Happy to help. Oh and, if the `$startdate` and `$enddate` variables are coming from user input, make sure you know what SQL injection is and how to prevent it. Otherwise, your application/website might be vulnerable for attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert it to a greater than and less than equation:

```
 date > '$startdate' AND date < '$enddate'
```

Comment: Hi, I have actually tried this before and it still wasn't working, thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with your SQL, but with your PHP.

You need to read up on how [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) works and how PHP treats strings that use `'` and `"` differently when wrapped around strings.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM record WHERE date BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate"';
```

Should be changed to one of the following:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM record WHERE date BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '"';
```

OR:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM record WHERE date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
```

*I've simplified the SQL to highlight the real issue at hand.*